# Call MySQL stored procedure using cursor.callproc() in python

Tags: python, mysql, stored-procedures, database-cursor

When I was trying to call the MySQL stored procedure using cursor.callproc()
I encountered some problems. When there were multiple input and output parameters, there was no problem and everything works fine as following:
I created procedure in MySQL like this with 5 input/output parameters:

```
create procedure enrollclass(in yeartime int, in quartertime char(20), in stid char(20), in course_no char(20), out result int)
```

and call procedure in python using something like this:

```
arg2 = ('2016', 'Q2', info[0][0], course_no, 0)
ac = cursor.callproc('enrollclass',arg2)
```

this worked fine. However, if I called another procedure with only one input parameter (with no output parameter) like this:

```
create procedure prerequisite( in course_no char(20))
```

and called the procedure using this line:

```
  arg3 = ('INFO1101')
  cursor.callproc('prerequisite', arg3)
```

then the system kept giving me error message 'args must be a sequence'. I have no idea how to fix it since I have no other argument to form a sequence. Could someone tell me what's going on here? Thanks!

Comment: when creating args, instead of round brackets ( ) user square brackets [ ]  and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

You might think that

```python
arg3 = ('INFO1101')
```

would create a tuple containing a single element, but it doesn't. In that context the parentheses act as "order of operations" specifiers, e.g.

```python
foo = (2 + 1) * 4
```

To create a single-element tuple you need to add a comma, as in

```python
arg3 = ('INFO1101',)
```